# Cosa significa "rilasciare un foglio" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola ho letto:

> Ah, e sai chi è un altro? Carlino. Anche lui, sempre con l'“Uomo Qualunque” in tasca... Ricordatene, Mara: se si azzarda a venir qui, sbattigli la porta in faccia. Io tipi come lui non ce li voglio per casa. Razza di mascalzone! Dopo che gli s'era fatto grazia del passato... e anzi, a Volterra i compagni **gli avevano anche rilasciato un foglio**...

Dovete sapere che la vicenda narrata nel libro accade giusto dopo la liberazione d'Italia in seguito alla Seconda guerra mondiale. "I compagni" menzionati sono membri del partito comunista.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "gli avevano rilasciato un foglio" nel brano precedente. Immagino che si riferisca a qualche documento. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sì, "rilasciare un foglio" in questo contesto significa "rilasciare un documento", probabilmente per far sapere agli altri *compagni* che Carlino era una persona di fiducia, nonostante il suo passato.

In effetti, in una parte precedente dello stesso romanzo, il padre di Mara dice:

> Gli operai devono comandare, e i borghesi, più se ne mette al muro e meglio è. E senza pietà, questa volta: c'è qualcuno anche qui in paese che bisogna saldarglielo il conto. Vigliacchi che prima erano sempre in camicia nera... eh, me li ricordo, non dubitare. M'hanno fatto sputar sangue per vent'anni. Loro sempre al lavoro, e io niente...
>
> **E un altro è Carlino**, il tuo compaesano... **Quello è uno che ha picchiato**, altro che storie. Quando è ricomparso,
> io l'ho affrontato e gliel'ho detto in faccia cosa pensavo di lui. E lui sai cosa mi ha risposto? Che **era del comitato. E m'ha fatto vedere un foglio**... Questi sono gli sbagli, ti rendi conto, compagno? **Non si dovevano rilasciare fogli a nessuno.** S'era detto sempre, quando viene il momento, si sradica una volta per sempre la malerba. Ma sì, è bastato che venisse la moglie a piangere, oppure i figlioli... Come se uno, perchè ha moglie e figlioli, gli si dovessero perdonare **vent'anni di delinquenza**!

Poiché la vicenda è ambientata poco dopo la Liberazione, "vent'anni di delinquenza" sembra riferirsi a un passato di Carlino non solo come delinquente e *borghese*, ma anche all'interno del partito fascista. Pertanto, il "foglio" era stato scritto perché gli altri compagni si fidassero di lui, pur sapendo che Carlino era stato un fascista.

Comment: Grazie mille! Questo brano è all'inizio del romanzo e non ricordavo che anche lì si parlasse del "foglio" rilasciato a Carlino.